# CTE query in snowflake to traverse the hierarchy

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have an emp table that has data like below in Snowflake. I need to add a column with the col name ED_ID  will will point to the immediate ED_id in the hierarchy.  If there is no ED in the employee's hierarchy then ED_ID will be null.

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+
| loginName | loginID | managerid | department | title | managertitle |
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+
| asr       |      26 |        56 | is         | as    | vp           |
| meh       |      56 |        34 | is         | vp    | ed           |
| pra       |      34 |       345 | is         | ed    | md           |
| dav       |     345 |        65 | is         | md    | md           |
| erc       |      65 |       908 | is         | md    | md           |
| mev       |     908 |         1 | is         | md    | ce           |
| rup       |      32 |        77 | ec         | vp    | vp           |
| pra       |      77 |        67 | ec         | vp    | vp           |
| ail       |      67 |       101 | ec         | vp    | md           |
| jen       |     101 |        97 | ec         | md    | md           |
| kim       |      97 |         1 | ec         | md    | ce           |
| shr       |      17 |        90 | td         | as    | vp           |
| dan       |      90 |       333 | td         | vp    | vp           |
| ruh       |     333 |       123 | td         | vp    | ed           |
| fin       |     123 |        39 | td         | ed    | ed           |
| sam       |      39 |         9 | td         | ed    | md           |
| aug       |       9 |       111 | td         | md    | md           |
| jun       |     111 |         1 | td         | md    | ce           |
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+
```

So recursive query should transform above table like below

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+------+
| loginName | loginID | managerid | department | title | managertitle | Edid |
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+------+
| asr       |      26 |        56 | is         | as    | vp           |   34 |
| meh       |      56 |        34 | is         | vp    | ed           |   34 |
| pra       |      34 |       345 | is         | ed    | md           |      |
| dav       |     345 |        65 | is         | md    | md           |      |
| erc       |      65 |       908 | is         | md    | md           |      |
| mev       |     908 |         1 | is         | md    | ce           |      |
| rup       |      32 |        77 | ec         | vp    | vp           |      |
| pra       |      77 |        67 | ec         | vp    | vp           |      |
| ail       |      67 |       101 | ec         | vp    | md           |      |
| jen       |     101 |        97 | ec         | md    | md           |      |
| kim       |      97 |         1 | ec         | md    | ce           |      |
| shr       |      17 |        90 | td         | as    | vp           |  123 |
| dan       |      90 |       333 | td         | vp    | vp           |  123 |
| ruh       |     333 |       123 | td         | vp    | ed           |  123 |
| fin       |     123 |        39 | td         | ed    | ed           |   39 |
| sam       |      39 |         9 | td         | ed    | md           |      |
| aug       |       9 |       111 | td         | md    | md           |      |
| jun       |     111 |         1 | td         | md    | ce           |      |
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+------+
```

I tried to write the below query it gives me the immediate ed if exists in the given hierarchy however I want the additional column to be filled based on the logic explained.

```
WITH RECURSIVE ManagerHierarchy AS (
SELECT Employee_Name, Employee_Manager_ID, Employee_Designation
FROM your_table_name
WHERE Employee_Name = 'asr'
UNION ALL
SELECT t.Employee_Name, t.Employee_Manager_ID, t.Employee_Designation
FROM your_table_name t
JOIN ManagerHierarchy m ON t.Employee_ID = m.Employee_Manager_ID  ) SELECT Employee_Name FROM ManagerHierarchy WHERE Employee_Designation = 'ED' LIMIT 1;
```

Could you please help me with the snowflake SQL query which will satisfy my requirement?

Comment: Add your table as plain text or CREATE table,INSERT values instruction. This will help you to suggest a solution

Comment: I tried to paste it as table but it is giving me option of image only

Comment: You can use stackoverflow's table markdown or a tool like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to format your table like text. Just highlight what you paste and click the `{}` button in the editor to preserve whitespace and line feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, can you create the new `edid` column in your recursive cte and conditionally fill it based on whether the `managertitle` is `ed`. In the recursive portion of the cte, if that check fails, then you just use the previous iterations `edid`.

This will look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName (loginName varchar(10), loginID int, managerid int, department varchar(10), title varchar(10), managertitle varchar(10));
INSERT INTO TableName(    loginName, loginID, managerid, department, title, managertitle) VALUES('    asr', 26, 56, 'is', 'as', 'vp')
,('    meh', 56, 34, 'is', 'vp', 'ed')
,('    pra', 34, 345, 'is', 'ed', 'md')
,('    dav', 345, 65, 'is', 'md', 'md')
,('    erc', 65, 908, 'is', 'md', 'md')
,('    mev', 908, 1, 'is', 'md', 'ce')
,('    rup', 32, 77, 'ec', 'vp', 'vp')
,('    pra', 77, 67, 'ec', 'vp', 'vp')
,('    ail', 67, 101, 'ec', 'vp', 'md')
,('    jen', 101, 97, 'ec', 'md', 'md')
,('    kim', 97, 1, 'ec', 'md', 'ce')
,('    shr', 17, 90, 'td', 'as', 'vp')
,('    dan', 90, 333, 'td', 'vp', 'vp')
,('    ruh', 333, 123, 'td', 'vp', 'ed')
,('    fin', 123, 39, 'td', 'ed', 'ed')
,('    sam', 39, 9, 'td', 'ed', 'md')
,('    aug', 9, 111, 'td', 'md', 'md')
,('    jun', 111, 1, 'td', 'md', 'ce');
```

```
WITH RECURSIVE reccte AS
(
  SELECT loginname, loginid, managerid, 
     department, title, managertitle, 
     CASE WHEN managertitle = 'ed' THEN managerid ELSE NULL END AS EDID, 
     managerid as parentid, 0 as recdepth
  FROM TableName --WHERE loginid = 26
  UNION ALL
  SELECT reccte.loginname, reccte.loginid, reccte.managerid, 
      reccte.department, reccte.title, reccte.managertitle, 
      CASE WHEN TableName.managertitle = 'ed' and reccte.edid IS NULL
         THEN TableName.managerid 
         ELSE reccte.edid END,
      TableName.managerid, reccte.recdepth + 1
  FROM reccte
    INNER JOIN TableName
       ON reccte.parentid = TableName.loginid
)
SELECT loginname, loginid, managerid, department, title, managertitle, edid
FROM (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY loginname ORDER BY recdepth desc) as rn FROM reccte) dt
WHERE rn = 1
```

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+------+
| loginname | loginid | managerid | department | title | managertitle | edid |
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+------+
| ail       |      67 |       101 | ec         | vp    | md           | null |
| asr       |      26 |        56 | is         | as    | vp           | 34   |
| aug       |       9 |       111 | td         | md    | md           | null |
| dan       |      90 |       333 | td         | vp    | vp           | 123  |
| dav       |     345 |        65 | is         | md    | md           | null |
| erc       |      65 |       908 | is         | md    | md           | null |
| fin       |     123 |        39 | td         | ed    | ed           | 39   |
| jen       |     101 |        97 | ec         | md    | md           | null |
| jun       |     111 |         1 | td         | md    | ce           | null |
| kim       |      97 |         1 | ec         | md    | ce           | null |
| meh       |      56 |        34 | is         | vp    | ed           | 34   |
| mev       |     908 |         1 | is         | md    | ce           | null |
| pra       |      34 |       345 | is         | ed    | md           | null |
| ruh       |     333 |       123 | td         | vp    | ed           | 123  |
| rup       |      32 |        77 | ec         | vp    | vp           | null |
| sam       |      39 |         9 | td         | ed    | md           | null |
| shr       |      17 |        90 | td         | as    | vp           | 123  |
+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+------+
```

Besides the case expression to populate `edid` as the recursive cte iterates up the hierarchy, there is also the bit in the actual `SELECT` at the bottom to grab only the last record that was iterated upon from the recursive portion of the sql. We do this by tracking the `depth` of the iteration in the `recdepth` column, and then only allowing the highest `recdepth` through to the final result set.